# Как правильно: упершись или уперевшись?

Tags: морфология

1. Упершись одной рукой в пол, Олег достал смартфон из заднего кармана и прочитал комментарий Нектоида на сайте вопросов по русскому языку.
2. Уперевшись одной рукой в пол, Олег достал смартфон из заднего кармана и прочитал комментарий Нектоида на сайте вопросов по русскому языку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильная форма деепричастия: **упёршись**.

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=280895).

P. S. Каким это, интересно, органом Олег из второго предложения достал смартфон, если обе руки заняты?.. Анекдот вспомнился про слона, который "капусту хвостом срывает и неприлично сказать куда себе засовывает".

Comment: Забыл поправить второе предложение. Исправил. Спасибо за ответ))

Comment: @Nektoid  Упершись – это некрасиво! Приличные писатели так пишут: Он сидел на полу, уперевшись лбом в решетку, уходящую вверх до потолка и забиравшую с обеих сторон пространство низкой и тесной арки, спереди открывался вид в зал, сзади проходили пути. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)] Совсем здесь "упершись" не походит.

Comment: @Sharon это и красиво, и единственный верный в литературном языке вариант. В Нацкорпусе "уперевшись" — 39 вхождений, "упершись" — 583. БТС также не указывает вариант "уперевшись": https://i.imgur.com/9ixLgEE.png А что там Глуховский в своей первой книге писал, роли не играет: первая книга его вообще отвратительна с точки зрения стилистики текста.

Comment: Здесь такая ситуация. Люди с развитым чувством языка (хорошие писатели) пишут так, как считают правильно, а остальные списывают их словаря Кузнецова. Если обратиться к грамматике, то используются три суффикса (В, ШИ, ВШИ), причем ВШИ характерен для возвратных форм, Но формально после основ на согласную используется ШИ (здесь усечение основы: упереться - уперся). Поэтому и существуют две формы, и вот форма "упершись" очень сомнительна. Глагол многозначный: можно упереться лбом в решетку, а в другом значении "Кто-л. упёрся и не слышит доводов". И вот эта разница слышится в деепричастной форме.

Comment: @Sharon пишут так, как считают правильным, все подряд, а не только люди с развитым чувством языка. Более того, по опыту редактуры знаю: чем невежественнее человек в вопросах стиля, тем сильнее убеждён, что пишет хорошо, просто его, бедного, никто не понимает, гения. Сколько я хулы на Розенталя слышал — не пересказать. И не надо Кузнецова так незаметненько выводить из числа людей с развитым чувством языка. Можете сколько угодно сомневаться в форме "упершись", но даже голая статистика (я приводил цифры) говорит за неё. Факт, как говорил Воланд, самая упрямая в мире вещь.

Comment: А Емец тоже писал "уперевшись", а еще Набоков и Андрей Белый. Я вам доказательства привожу: способы образования, причину наличия двух форм, а вы однозначность любите больше, чем сам факты, о которых говорил Воланд, вот что грустно...

Comment: @Sharon ошибки у всех могут быть. Даже у Набокова; или же на тот момент ещё не было словарной однозначности.

Comment: Многие менее именитые современные  писатели и сейчас так пишут,  а однозначность – это сомнительное достоинство.  Разные формы позволяют нам позволяют нам выразить различные  семантические оттенки. И однозначность обедняет наш язык, ага?

Comment: @Sharon не многие. Ещё раз привожу статистику: "уперевшись" — 39 вхождений, "упершись" — 583.

Comment: Еще раз не надо. И я желаю вам побольше однозначности во всем, если вы ее так любите. Кстати, вы в этих 39 примерах семантику посмотрите, для вашего персонажа она вполне подходит...

Comment: @Sharon у Набокова — я не поленился поискать — на всё собрание сочинений единожды "уперевшись", трижды "упершись". В одинаковых контекстах.  *...потом останавливалась, уперевшись одной ногой в край панели... / Она встала, сильно в него упершись... /  Она вдруг согнулась вдвое и зарыдала, упершись локтями в колени... / ... стояла, упершись руками в бока...* // И не надо ошибку называть семаническим оттенком, неоднозначностью и проч. Эдак можно что угодно оправдать.

Comment: Вот именно, когда упираются лбом, рукой (чем-то обо что-то), больше подходит "уперевшись". Ну ладно, не буду вас больше расстраивать, а то будете всю ночь Набокова и Белого перечитывать.

Comment: @Sharon как жаль, что Набоков не знал, что "больше подходит "уперевшись"", и трижды использовал "упершись", именно когда персонаж упирается частью тела о кого-то или обо что-то.

Comment: Ну да, колебался,  думал. наверное, как писать: по чувству языка или по словарю Кузнецова.  Или, как вариант, наши лингвисты его подредактировали :))